# How can I trimmed NSMutableString when other NSMutableString is not to be trimmed in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I am facing problem while removing blank space from NSMutableString.
I am using code like this:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(!myMutableStringSiteObj)
        myMutableStringSiteObj = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
    {
        [myMutableStringSiteObj appendString:string];
        NSString *trimmedString = [myMutableStringSiteObj stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [myMutableStringSiteObj setString:trimmedString];

        NSData *datasite = [myMutableStringSiteObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        responseSitedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datasite options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responseSitedict);
    }

    myMutableStringObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObj);
    NSData *data = [myMutableStringObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedict);

    myMutableStringbranchObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringbranchObj);
    NSData *databranch = [myMutableStringbranchObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsebranchdict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:databranch options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsebranchdict);
}
```

In this code there are three string one string contain space and other two string does not contain space. First it take Id of myMutableStringObj then   myMutableStringbranchObj and then myMutableStringSiteObj. But when it come to myMutableStringSiteObj app get crash because it contain blankspace. But code of trimming string doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think doing that within the XML parser is a good idea.  You don't know anything about the text fragments delivered to that delegate method.  I think you are better doing this once you have the complete document so you trim the correct elements.

Comment: @Droppy I dont know anything about ext fragments delivered to that delegate method what is it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want trim a string (removing first & last spaces) then you can use following function.

```
 NSString *newString = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: That I am already using. But there are other two string also that why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works
 NSString *Spacetrimmed = [foo stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

Comment: that I am already using. But there is other two string also that why it is not working.